Phone restarts when adding a certain Wi-Fi network with a notice "Network needs to be verified Review network details for "SSID" before connecting"
I am trying to add a certain wi-fi network on my Galaxy S24 Plus.
That results in the whole phone restarting (at least, I think it does) and I get this notice:

Network needs to be verified Review network details for "blah" before
connecting. Tap to continue.

What is a possible cause?

Looks like it's not device specific. There's a Reddit thread talking about the same issue on Pixel 6 and Pixel 7 Pro, that the only explanation is "I think it's something to do with the authentication settings of the WiFi network. I was told by someone from our IT department, that the current setup just straight up doesn't work with Pixel phones."

Checking the source code, looks like this is caused by an insecure EAP network, and Android tries to notify the user about CA certificate with this message. However, I'd like your confirmation of whether this is really the case before turning this into an answer (or you can post the answer with more information after troubleshooting it :).
